# TRAMP doesn't know some of the remote commands

Tags: tramp, ssh, remote, zsh

I'm using my local emacs to edit files on a remote cluster. Therefore I added:

```
[[ $TERM == "dumb" ]] && unsetopt zle && PS1='$ ' && return
```

to my remote .zshrc and I can edit and browse files without any problems. I can even compile (M-x compile) file using:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

I checked: It runs on the cluster and not my local machine, however if I run:

```
mpicc -std=c99 -Wall -o exec heat.c
/bin/sh: line 2: mpicc: command not found
```

If I do the same in a regular SSH-Session it works without any problems.

How can I use mpicc on the cluster from emacs?

emacs -Q doesn't help.

Comment: Does this have to do with your PATH? (i.e. do you make modifications to the path that you are skipping for dumb terminals?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $PATH settings in your init file are not taken into account per default. Try the following:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path)
```

See also the Tramp manual discussing this setting.

Comment: At first it didn't work, because 'tramp-remote-path was void, but (require 'tramp) fixed it.